# Maven in Intelij not download

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project in intelij , when i add the followng dependency :

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
     <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
     <version>2.8.8</version>
     <scope>compile</scope>
 </dependency>
```

i see the Librairie in the external Librairies but when i when to use it intelij not recognize the Class after i add the Maven Dependency the class stay in red :

[image]

If someone can help me I'm starting in maven ...
thank you

Comment: thanks for then answer , yes i tried to import it when i reset the cache and I import the gson class he proposes me to add the class in the compiler option and now it's working . How can I automatically add the dependence to the compiler option if someone know ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, which is why I'll leave an answer instead.

Did you even try to import the GSON class?

`import com.google.gson.Gson;`

Since you didn't post any usable code I'm just guessing as to what the problem might be. If your dependency shows up and your import doesn't work, it may be worth it to clear IntelliJ's cache. I've had various situations where IntelliJ just wouldn't pull in dependencies despite having access to them.

Cleaning the cache should be a last resort, but it might be worth it if nothing else works.

Cheers,

-T